# ARKit: Removing ARSCNView shows static camera feed instead of top-most SCNView

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit, arscnview, sceneview

Our app shows a SCNView by default but lets users enter AR mode, where we show a ARSCNView on top of the SCNView.

Showing the ARSCNView works: the camera and virtual objects appear.

Exiting AR mode is what fails.

Instead of showing the SCNView underneath the ARSCNView, what remains on the screen is a static image of the camera feed right before removing the ARSCNView.

What's the right way to "exit" AR mode and remove an ARSCNView?

```
self.arSceneView!.removeFromSuperview()
self.arSceneView = nil
```

Answer (score 1):

So I believe you can successfully continue on the current route you are on. Where you have one view controller and multiple arscnviews. An alternative to do this would be to have one parent view controller and two children view controllers with their own separate scnviews. To make this work you would have to add and remove the scnviews from the parent view controller's view.  However, this last step seems to be what you are trying to make work with the one view controller route you are on. If you want to stay with one view controller, I recommend having a container for the ARSCNViews and adding and removing those views from the ViewController's view like so:

When adding exampleViewA and removing exampleViewB

```
self.view.addSubview(exampleViewA)
exampleViewB.removeFromSuperview()
```

and vice versa for adding exampleViewB and revmoing exampleViewA

```
self.view.addSubview(exampleViewB)
exampleViewA.removeFromSuperview()
```

But in order to do this, the act of moving back and forth between views, you should have a container that remembers/store your ARSCNViews like so:

```
var arSCNViews: [String:ARSCNView] = {
return [
          "exampleViewA": exampleViewA,
          "exampleViewB": exampleViewB
]()
```